# CakePHP validation with OR condition in Model

Tags: cakephp

i am developing a form where a user can be filled either mobile no. OR telephone no. or both. so i want to add validation to do this.

cakephp version : 2.5

```
'mobile' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message'=> 'Please enter mobile'
        )

'telephone' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message'=> 'Please enter telephone'
        )
```

i want to combination of both with OR condition in Model.

Comment: please always set the version of cakephp,however this time is obvious its 2.x but sometime not easy to recognize quick.
What you looking for is the Conditional Validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Get the Conditional Behaviour from here:
[Conditional Validation Behavior](https://github.com/cwbit/cakephp-conditionalvalidation)

Add Behavior to your model:

```
class Something extends AppModel
{
    public $actsAs = array('ConditionalValidation');
}
```

Defining your validation rule by Model:

```
class Something extends AppModel
{
    public $actsAs = array('ConditionalValidation');

    public $validate = array(
        'telephone' => array('isActive' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'if' => array('mobile',''),//activate when you don't have mobile
            ),
'mobile' => array('isActive' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'if' => array('telephone',''),//activate when you don't have mobile
            ),



        );
    );
}
```

Have to find out whats the rule for both fields exist

Comment: you can try the following:
telephone:
'if' => array('mobile',''),('mobile')//empty or exist
mobile:
'if' => array('telephone',''),('telephone')//empty or exist.
I can not test it but please write back if it is cover the exist both
fields case